Regular expression for filename consisting of word, then number, then extension
I got unexpected results using this simple regular expression. Say the current directory contains the following files:
foo.txt
foo1.txt
foo2.txt
foo123.txt
foo1_bar.txt

I would like to list all files of the form fooNNN.txt, where NNN is a sequence of 1 or more digits. I thought the following regular expression would work:
ls foo[0-9]*.txt

however that produces the output (in Bash shell):
foo1.txt  foo123.txt  foo1_bar.txt  foo2.txt

Why is it picking up foo1_bar.txt and can I improve the regular expression to exclude foo1_bar.txt ? (and continue to exclude foo.txt)

wasn't sure if this is better suited to SO or SU, please let me know if I should delete & repost at SU

With ls, you are using glob wildcards, not regex. Use shopt -s extglob and then ls foo*([0-9]).txt. To disable the extglob, use shopt -u extglob

@WiktorStribiżew is there any reason to not have extglob on all the time?  and could you perhaps write an answer explaining exactly what [0-9]* is doing ?

You might be better of using find with a regex.

You may consider reading "Options which change globbing behavior"

@WiktorStribiżew ls is neither using wildcards nor regex. It's a job for the shell to expand patterns.

I find your question a bit confusing: In the title, you mention a regex, but there is none in your code, and in your tags you mention glob, not regex anyway. Actually, what you want to achieve indeed would be a task for wildcards.

@M.M if you rely on extglob being on all the time then your code won't be portable to other shells that don't support extglob and may break existing scripts you call that rely on traditional non-extglob behavior.

Globbing is NOT regex.
ls foo[0-9]*.txt

Is using CLI globbing, so the interpreter parses the glob and replaces it with the list of files that match before ls sees it, just as it would with echo or anything else. Your glob passes ls all files that start with foo followed by a digit, followed by zero or more characters, folowed by .txt. What you wanted was one or more digits, which you really can't do with standard globbing.
Extended globbing gets close.
shopt -s extglob
printf "%s\n" foo+([0-9]).txt

which will report (from the list you gave above)
foo1.txt
foo123.txt
foo2.txt

For an actual regex, you'd either need to farm out to another program -
$: echo * | grep -Eo 'foo[0-9]+.txt'
foo1.txt
foo123.txt
foo2.txt

Or use a loop, both of which are also mentioned elsewhere here.

In my Git Bash environment on my laptop, I use shopt in my ~/.bash_profile to enable extglob and globstar all the time. Just don't alter someone else's defaults without discussing it first.

You didn't say what you mean by word, but let's assume that it is a sequence of one or more lower case or upper case letters:
I think that for your problem, a regex would be suited best.
Solution 1: Using gnu find (if you are on a mac, you have to install it first)
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '.+/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+'

Note that since -regex matches the whole path, you have to test for the directory separator as well.
Solution 2: Test each file separately:
for file in *
do
  [[ $file =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+$ ]] && echo $file

done


-regextype egrep is useless as last option, because it is relevant only for later options.

@Wiimm: Thanks. Didn't know it. I have updated my answer.
